# Non clustered index on partitioned table

Tags: sql-server-2012, partitioning, nonclustered-index

Using SQL Server 2012. I have a huge table that is partitioned. I need to create a non clustered index on it.

After I created the index, a job that somewhere switches partition fails because the index I create. (The job works fine once I remove the index)

My question is what are the things I need to take in account while creating the index on partitioned table.

Answer (score 4):

Your job *most likely* blew up because you added the non-clustered index to the base table, but did not add it to the *staging* table required for switching partitions in and out.

There are a significant number of things to consider when using partition switching - please read [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx).  From that post.

> Nonclustered indexes must be defined and must be identical. Any
> nonclustered indexes that are defined on the target table are also
> defined on the source table and are structured identically in terms of
> uniqueness, subkeys, and the sorting direction (ASC or DESC) for each
> index key column. Nonclustered indexes that are disabled are exempt
> from this requirement.